# How to get 7z parameters values

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

I've found that the (undocumented) 7z `-mx4` option gives the best time/compression ratio for my files:

```
7z a -r -mx4 outfile.7z infile.dat
```

Now I'd like to fine tune the parameters to get even better results. But I don't have the starting point. I've tried these values listed [in documentation](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm#7Z), but both the compression time and the resulting filesize were larger:

```
7z a -r -m0=LZMA2:a=0:d=1m:mf=hc4:fb=32:mc=32:lc=3:lp=0:pb=2 outfile.7z infile.dat
```

Is there any way to get the actual values for all the parameters 7z used?

Comment: *Is there any way to get the actual values for all the parameters 7z used?* Take default settings (they are listed in documentation), override them with environ variable settings, then override with command line settings - and you will obtain actual settings applied/

Comment: @Akina thanks, but the default settings are not listed for `-mx4` and I failed to guess them.

Comment: `-mx4` is not described at all. So it is unknown what is it, what method with what settings is applied, and why 7z does not report about wrong parameter... I think that the developers are the only who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to obtain only the dictionary size from a 7z archive, but that was enough to figure out all other settings. One can get the dictionary size with the `l` command, the output would contain a line like

```
Method = LZMA2:22
```

here `22` is the dict size. It's equivalent to `4m` (2**22 B = 4 MiB).

The remaining parameters could be guessed one by one. The equivalent to `-mx4` shorthand is the following command line:

```
7z a -r -m0=LZMA2:a=0:d=22:mf=hc4:fb=32:mc=16:lc=3:lp=0:pb=2 outfile.7z infile.dat
```